# Why is volley for Android not sending my parameters in my GET/POST requests?

Tags: android, http, android-volley

Im trying to make a GET request using Volley android library but when I do I check the server and the request was received but the parameters dont. I have tried this with POST and GET but none have worked. This is my code

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, all ,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("t","inVLlhZ0I29tPpoLGpBO9KzVI0zM-3ED3KiTcAuCUJ65TBbUZBnmCg");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Also Ive tried using a class and creating a custom request and overriding the getParams method within the class but it have the same result.

This was the custom request class I used:

```
public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

    private Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public CustomRequest(String url, Map<String, String> params,
                         Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    public CustomRequest(int method, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                         Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = reponseListener;
        this.params = params;
    }

    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        return params;
    };

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

}
```

Comment: As far as I know, GET doesn't use body parameters like POST. Please show a POST example as well as how you are testing the request on the server side

Comment: As cricket says, GET doesn't use parameters, it appends its parameters as a query string to the URL.

Comment: @GabeSechan Ok I get now that I can not pass body params in a GET request, but how can I achieve then appending the parameters to the URL in Android?. I achieved this in iOS with Alamofire just passing them as normal parameters.

Comment: @ravelinx Ever see a URL with a ? in it?  Everything after the ? is the query string.  It holds the parameters.  Maybe iOS does some magic and appends them for you, if so that's a pretty bad idea, since a POST can actually have query and body parameters.

Comment: Oh and if you're using a URI object to hold the URL, it has functions to append query parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers I received I came with a solution that was to append to the url the parameters I needed like this:

String url = String.format(myUrl +"?**nameOfParameter**=%1$s",**parameterContent**);

So if need to make a GET request with this parameter ("t", "1234") with a url equal to www.mypage.com/request/

I would write the following(The page should come from an attribute but I wrote it in order to explain the idea) ;

```
   public void request() {

        String url = String.format("www.mypage.com/request/" + "?t=%1$s","1234");

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, pos ,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Code here
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       // Code here
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```